# Negative Lookbehind stops after first occurrence of an optional regex

Tags: regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I'm removing protocol from links in HTML files using the following regex in Python:

```
re.sub(r"((http:|https:)?(\/\/website.com))", r"\3", result)
```

This works as expected, but I don't want to replace the protocol when the attribute is `content`. So I started looking into using Regex Negative Lookbehind.

```
(?<!content=")(http:|https:)?(\/\/website.com)
```

This regex should basically mean that if the string starts with `<content="`, then it should not match the rest. But the problem is that it only rejects the optional regex, `(http:|https:)?`, likely because it's optional. It rejects the whole line if it's not optional.

Here's a screenshot that shows the problem clearly. The first line should be rejected completely, but it only rejected the protocol.

[image: Picture of the regex problem]

Any suggestions? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the original regex is that it matches `//website.com` that does not have `content="` directly before it, because the `http:`/`https:` is optional.  To workaround it, you can include the protocol in the negative lookbehind.

As variable length lookbehinds are not supported in Python, you can do the following:

```
(?<!content=")(?<!content="https:)(?<!content="http:)((https?:)?(//website.com))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wI4sQ6/1)

Answer (score 1):

The regex finds `//website.com` that does not have `content="` directly in front of it. So returns a match.

How about

```
(?<!content="|content="http:|content="https:)(http:|https:)?(\/\/website.com)
```